# Get username using select prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I wrote this code, but it is just outputting "1". It should output the username of the selected user.

```
$uid = $_GET['id'];
if (empty($uid)) {
    echo "Error: Wrong input of values.";
} else {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM usersinfo WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $uid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
    echo $result;
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: I don't see any return at all.

Comment: @MarkusZeller      I mean in "return" the "echo", i'm sorry i not good in php

Comment: Read the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.fetch-returnvalues

Answer (score 3):

[`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) doesn't return the results. There is no useful information returned by that function. What you need to do is get the mysqli result. There are 2 ways to do it.

The simpler way:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM usersinfo WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $uid);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); // Get the result of the above statement.
$firstRow = $result->fetch_array(); // Get the first result into an array
if ($firstRow) {
    echo $firstRow[0];
    //or
    echo $firstRow['username'];
}
```

Here we get the mysqli result object and then we ask for a single row.

Another way using `bind_result()`:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM usersinfo WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $uid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username); // Bind a single column from SELECT to a single variable
$stmt->fetch(); // Fetch the first row. It will populate the variable
echo $username;
```

This is more difficult to read in my opinion. Also if you wanted to get more columns it would quickly get very complicated.

To be honest mysqli is not very friendly and is very cumbersome to use. I strongly recommend to switch to PDO, but if you can't try to encapsulate the mysqli functions in some class or function. YCS has an example of such [helper function.](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple) I have recently written an [example of how to extend a mysqli class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60210442/1839439) with a wrapper class.

I have added a simple method to the mysqli class and take a look how simpler the statements have become.

```
class DBClass extends mysqli {
    public function __construct(
        $host = null,
        $username = null,
        $passwd = null,
        $dbname = null,
        $port = null,
        $socket = null
    ) {
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        parent::__construct($host, $username, $passwd, $dbname, $port, $socket);
        $this->set_charset('utf8mb4');
    }

    public function safeQuery(string $sql, array $params = []): ?array {
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        if ($params) {
            $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($params)), ...$params);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {
            return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
$results = $conn->safeQuery("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ?", [$uid]);
if($results){
    echo $results[0][0]; // first row, first column 
    // or 
    echo $results[0]['username']; // first row, get column by name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this,

I have used `->fetch_assoc();` so us to fetch the results in an array as opposed to `->fetch();` which has been used in the question

in case username has duplicates:- then

```
   $uid = $_GET['id'];
    if (empty($uid)) {
        echo "Error: Wrong input of values.";
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM usersinfo WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $uid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  { //fetch_assoc() function fetches a result row as an associative array - here we are putting it in a loop
          echo $row['username'];
         }

        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
```

If we are to retrieve just one result, assuming there are no duplicates we can use below without loop.

```
   $uid = $_GET['id'];
    if (empty($uid)) {
        echo "Error: Wrong input of values.";
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM usersinfo WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $uid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

         $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); //fetch_assoc() function fetches a result row as an associative array
         echo $row['username']; //we can specify just to return specific column i.e. username

        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
```

Comment: I have used `->fetch_assoc();` so us to fetch the results in an array as opposed to `->fetch();` which has been used in the question

Comment: This has been actioned